# How to implement setInterval() function with interval as Minutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I got work like I need to call an API in the background every 28 minutes, So I thought of using setInterval to achieve this, but is it possible to set interval in minutes?

```
useEffect(() => {
setInterval(() => {
  //dispatch API here
},??)
})
```

Now here I need to run this every 28 minutes, How can I implement this?

If there are other possible ways to achieve my requirement also, please do recommend that way too.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `1000 * 60 * minutes`??

Comment: @Madhan1021 there are two good answers bellow you can mark as accepted.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier, yea bud I accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setInterval accepts the `delay` parameter in milliseconds.  A millisecond is 1 1000th (1/1000) of a second.

So if you want a delay of 28 minutes, you need to work out how many seconds this is (28*60) and then multiply that by 1000.

So 28 * 60 * 1000 = 1,680,000

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Richard.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` accepts milliseconds, so you can calculate it to minutes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const minutes = 28 * 60 * 1000;
    setInterval(() =>{
        console.log('hello world');
    }, minutes);
});
```